# CSS3 Pie integration with Wordpress in ie8 does not work

Tags: html, wordpress, css, css3pie

Using border-radius I am creating cirlce to support border-radius I am using CSS3 pie then also in ie it is not working. 
I put CSS3 pie file in my theme folder & in `style.css` write code:

```
#sidebar {
 width:140px;
 height:140px;
 margin:0 auto;
 -moz-border-radius: 70px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 70px;
 border-radius: 70px;
 behavior: url(PIE.htc);
 background-color:#fff;
 position:relative;
 z-index: 0;
}
```

Comment: Hello sir, This is my website link http://achieveee.com/elemnt/

Answer (score 1):

Isn't the most simple hack to make the URL to pie absolute;

```
#sidebar {
 width:140px;
 height:140px;
 margin:0 auto;
 -moz-border-radius: 70px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 70px;
 border-radius: 70px;
 behavior: url(http://yoursite.com/wp-content/themes/themename/css/PIE.htc);
 background-color:#fff;
 position:relative;
 z-index: 0;
}
```

I've had to do that on an irritating install that would never work with relative paths.

Answer (score 0):

.htc files need their paths to be relative to the root of the site.

CSS paths are relative the stylesheet. It's Microsoft being pests again.

Move the PIE.htc file to the root of your site and this should work.

Comment: I created folder in my theme folder as pie & put all css3 pie files  in that folder. The stylesheet as follow :-
#sidebar ul li  { border-radius:70px; -moz-border-radius:70px;
        behavior: url("http://localhost/travel_logs/blog/wp-content/themes/travel_logs/pie/PIE.htc");
        position: relative;
        zoom: 1;
}

Comment: Yeah don't. Put the .htc file in the root. The path has to be relative to the root. NOT the stylesheet.

Comment: sorry but i did that also it's not working.In simple html site its working but in wordpress it is not working.

Comment: Ok so the .htc file is on the root. Is the CSS still pointing to (PIE.htc)?

Comment: That should do the trick. Withouth seeing the site this is too localised to help properly. Sorry.

Comment: you can check on achieveee.com/elemnt

Comment: Well for starts the htc file does not appear in your CSS at all.

Comment: plz check now. bcoz i put condition for ie in css that why its not visible.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put pie.htc in the root. Something like this `www.domainname.com/PIE.htc` or if you are developing on your local machine, then `http://localhost/[your installation folder]/PIE.htc`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: sorry but it not help me bcoz already i did that its not working in ie.